# Ошибка "invalid indirection", указывающая на индексы массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Вот, собственно, вся программа...

```
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 void  vyvod(float*,int,int);   //Скорей всего неверно что-то здесь//
 int vnutri(float,float);
 float pryamaya(float,float,float,float);
 void sort(float*,int,int);
 int main()
 {
 int i,j=0,l=0;
 float k,b,A[15][3],B[15][4],C[15][6],r;
 clrscr();
 printf("Vvedite coefficienty functii y=kx+b\nk=");
 scanf("%f",&k);//k=10.5//
 printf("\nb=");
 scanf("%f",&b);//b=-64//
 FILE *file1;
 file1=fopen("POINTS.txt","rt");
 for(i=0;i<15;i++)
 { A[i][0]=i+1;
 fscanf(file1,"%f,%f;",&A[i][1],&A[i][2]);
     } //Здесь всё нормально из файла считывается...//

     printf("Massiv D1\n  N    x    y");
 vyvod(&A[0][0],15,3); //А  здесь при обращении к функции начинаются проблемы//
 for(i=0;i<15;i++)
 {
 l=vnutri(A[i][1],A[i][2]);
 if(l==1)
 { B[j][0]=j+1;
 B[j][1]=A[i][0];
 B[j][2]=A[i][1];
 B[j][3]=A[i][2];
 j=j+1; }
 }
 printf("Massiv D2\n  N2   N1    x    y");
 vyvod(&B[0][0],j,4);  //Ну и здесь соответственно тоже аналогично...//
 l=0;
 for(i=0;i<j;i++)
 {
 r=pryamaya(B[i][2],B[i][3],k,b);
 if(r<=3.2)
 {
 C[l][0]=l+1;
 C[l][1]=B[i][0];
 C[l][2]=B[i][1];
 C[l][3]=B[i][2];
 C[l][4]=B[i][3];
 l++;
 }
 }
 printf("Massiv D3\n  N    x    y");
 vyvod(&C[0][0],l,6);
 sort(&C[0][0],l,6);
 vyvod(&C[0][0],l,6);
 getch();
 fclose(file1);
 return(0);
 }

 void vyvod(float *A,int a,int b) //Здесь почему-то массив не передаётся ф-ции//
 {
 int i,j;
 FILE *file2;
 file2=fopen("MASSIVES.txt","at");
 for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{ for(j=0;j<b;j++)
{
 printf("%5.1f",A[i][j]);
 fprintf(file2,"%5.1f",A[i][j]);
}
 printf("\n");
fprintf(file2,"\n");
}
 fclose(file2);
 }

 int vnutri(float x,float y)
{ int m=x;
float k=0,min,max;
 switch(m)
{ case 1:max=10;min=1;break;
 case 2:
 case 3: max=9;min=1;break;
case 4:
case 5:
 case 6: max=8;min=1;break;
case 7:
case 8:
 case 9: max=7;min=1;break;
case 10:
case 11:
 case 12: max=6;min=1;break;
case 13: max=4;min=1;break;
case 14: max=2;min=1;break;
 case 15: max=0;min=0;break;
}
if (y>=min && y<=max)
 k=1;
return(k);
}
float pryamaya(float x,float y,float k,float b)
 { float r;
r=k*x-b;
y=fabs(y-r);
x=y/k;
 r=(x*y)/sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2));
return(y);
}

 void sort(float *C,int a,int b)
{
int i,j,t;
for(i=0;i<a-1;i++)
 { if(C[i][b-1]>C[i+1][b-1])
{
 for(j=0;j<b;j++)
 { t=C[i][j];
 C[i][j]=C[i+1][j];
 C[i+1][j]=t;}
}
}
 }
```

Comment: Да уж, в вашем коде очень сложно разобраться... Но для начала такой вопрос, что эта программа должна делать? Хотя бы вкратце.

Comment: И еще, у сообщения стоит метка С++, тогда почему вы используете сишные методы ввода и вывода, ведь cout и cin попроще, да и программа выглядит понятнее!?

Comment: я думаю, что автору вопроса было бы полезно ознакомиться с понятием "форматированный код"

Comment: Да пардон,это обычный СИ,перепутал...

В программе надо извлечь из файла координаты точек,занести их в двумерный массив,затем вывести на экран этот массив,и потом его изменить кое-где и опять вывести.

Там скорей всего проблема с передачей этого массива в функцию.

Answer (score 1):

Так Вы неправильно передаете в функцию двумерный массив. Надо передавать так:

```
void vyvod(float A[][10], int a, int b)
```

где 10 - константа (написал для примера), указывающая на длину этого измерения массива.

Если же передаете просто указатель, то получать элемент (например A[m][n]) массива A[y][x] надо так:

```
*(A + x*m + n)
```

Наверно, есть и другие ошибки, но эту вижу сразу.

Comment: разве конструкция `A[m][n]` не разворачивается в `*(A + x*m + n)`? UPD Из-за этого `5[a]` - тоже самое, что и `a[5]`

Comment: Для этого компилятор должен знать базу массива, т.е. x. А если передается просто указатель, как он ее будет знать?

Comment: @mikillskegg понял, спасибо